# Curl API Call using PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I hope all is well with you. I ran into some trouble with a project im currently working on and I thought I’d asked to see if someone can take a look at it for me? Basically what I want to happen is to pull all my events from the purplepass api and bring it to the website that im working on. Do you think you can help me out?

API Link: https://www.purplepass.com/api/docs.html

**I keep getting this error: {”success”:false, “errors”:{“reason”:“Invalid section”} **

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

 <?php

    // Making the API Call to Purplepass
    function callAPI($method, $url, $data){
        $curl = curl_init();

        switch ($method){
            case "POST":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                if ($data)
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                break;
        }

       // OPTIONS:
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'APIKEY: 111111111111111111111',
          'Content-Type: application/json',
       ));
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
       // Execute:
       $result = curl_exec($curl);
       if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
       curl_close($curl);
       print($result);
       return $result;
    }
    // Setting up the credentials for authentication:
    $login =  array(
        "section" => "login",
        "action" => "login",
        "login_email" => "fake@email.com",
        "login_passwd" => "fakepassword"
    );
    // URL needed for API Call:
    $url = "https://www.purplepass.com/api/";
    $make_call = callAPI('POST', $url, json_encode($login));
    $response = json_decode($make_call, true);
 ?>
</body>
```

Comment: docs sez 'login_passwd' , not 'login_password'

Comment: It appears that one of the criteria is not correct `login_password` => `login_passwd`. I've never used purplepass, but noted that based on the docs link that you provided.

Comment: I changed the login_password => login_passwd but am still getting the same result?

Comment: not sure if you really need to `json_encode($login)`!? try once without (plain array passed) and with `http_build_query($login)`. json_encode is defenitely wrong here.

Comment: Hi @jeff thanks for your response. I did try both ways but still ran into the same issue.

Comment: This seems a very straighforward error message. "Invalid section" suggests the value you've passed as "section" is not valid. This really seems like something you should take up with the maintainer of this API.

Comment: Thank you @miken32 I just thought I could solve this issue without getting in contact with them but I will do so now that it is suggested. Thank you

Comment: It's just too specific a problem to be a good fit for SO. The idea being that questions should have value to future visitors.